# Django Loop inside Model.py to check if previous ID exist in DB or NOT

Tags: django, django-models

```
def getPreID(self):
    preid=self.id-1
    preid1 = TourScene.objects.filter(id = preid)
    if not preid1:
        preid =preid-1
```

What I want here exactly is when I am getting self.id I need the previous Id 
so I did **preid=self.id-1**, Now I want to check if this preid exist or not if not I want to next previous ID.

So how Can I run this in loop to check if id not exist check previous if previous not exist then check next previous ID.. so ...

please help me out because I am new to python.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might be trying to get an id to create a new database row. In general much better to let Django work out the id of the new object on its own, by leaving id unspecified. What you want is likely to suffer from race conditions - that is if two processes try to work out a free id at the same time they will both pick the same value.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your reply.But Here I trying to check because need the previous  and Next id .Suppose I have series of 10 images and some of the middle image id has been deleted then in that case I need to check that which Id exist and which doesnot exist

Answer (score 0):

If you want your function to return the previous id, or `None` if it does not exist:

```
def getPreID(self):
    preid = self.id - 1
    while preid != 0:
        if TourScene.objects.filter(id=preid):
            return preid
        preid = preid - 1
    return None
```

Comment: It didn't work for me.I solve the problem in some different way.                                What I did is I stored all the ID in array and then find the position of **self.id**  image then get the previous image **self.id image position -1** and the next image as **self.id image  position+1**                                        Because I have lit of 100-1000 images and if some of the images deleted in the middle of series then self.id-1 and self.id+1 was not working.